# Rotar imágenes con fondos transparentes

Tags: php, imagen

Estoy intentando rotar una imagen con transparencia.

Este código funciona, excepto cuando es un ángulo de 90°, 180°, 270° y 360°. Con esos grados, me crea un fondo negro.

```
$grados = 90;
$width = 191;
$height = 65;
$logo = 'logo.png';
$resizeImagenNueva = 'nuevologo.png';

//cambiar tamaño
$logo = imagecreatefrompng($logo);

$ximagen = imagesx($logo);
$yimagen = imagesy($logo);

$nuevoBlanco = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
transparenteImagen($nuevoBlanco, $width, $height);

//copiar imagen
imagecopyresampled($nuevoBlanco, $logo, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $ximagen, $yimagen);

imagepng($nuevoBlanco, $resizeImagenNueva);

//rotar
$imagenAlRotar = imagecreatefrompng($resizeImagenNueva);

$nuevoBlanco = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$transparenteRotate = transparenteImagenRotada($nuevoBlanco);
$rotar = imagerotate($nuevoBlanco, $grados, $transparenteRotate);
imagepng($rotar, $imagenRotada);
imagedestroy($imagenAlRotar);

function transparenteImagenRotada ($imagen)
{

    imagealphablending($imagen, false);
    imagesavealpha($imagen, true);
    $transparente = imagecolorallocatealpha($imagen, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagefill($imagen , 0, 0, $transparente);
    return $transparente;
}

function transparenteImagen ($imagen, $width, $height)
{
    imagealphablending($imagen, false);
    imagesavealpha($imagen, true);
    $transparente = imagecolorallocatealpha($imagen, 255,255,255, 127);
    imagefilledrectangle($imagen, 0, 0, $width, $height, $transparente);
}
```

¿Cómo puedo rotar una imagen respetando el fondo transparente para cualquier ángulo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Rotar una imagen con fondo transparente

Una vez que se cuenta con la imagen como recurso de tipo [GD](http://php.net/manual/es/book.image.php), la imagen se puede rotar fácilmente con la función [**imagerotate**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.imagerotate.php):

```php
resource imagerotate ( resource $image , float $angle , int $bgd_color [, int $ignore_transparent = 0 ] )
```

El único punto importante a considerar es que, al rotar una imagen, ocurre una mezcla (*blending*) en la transformación. Es lógico que ocurra con cada color en cada pixel, pero es necesario asegurarnos de que no se mezclen los valores para el canal alfa (que establece la transparencia). Tanto para el origen como para el destino, se debe configurar:

```php
imagealphablending($imagen, false);  //No mezclar sobre el canal alfa (transparencias)
imagesavealpha($imagen, true);      //guardar la información completa del canal alfa
```

---

**Código**

```php
<?php
//Parámetros
$archivo = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeayA.png'; //logo de SO
$angulo = 90;

//Generar el recurso de imagen original
$origen = imagecreatefrompng($archivo) or die('Error al abrir el archivo '.$archivo);
imagealphablending($origen, false);  //No mezclar sobre el canal alfa (transparencias)
imagesavealpha($origen, true);       //guardar la información completa del canal alfa

//Generar el recurso de imagen rotado
$destino = imagerotate($origen, $angulo, imageColorAllocateAlpha($origen, 0, 0, 0, 127));
imagealphablending($destino, false); //No mezclar sobre el canal alfa (transparencias)
imagesavealpha($destino, true);      //guardar la información completa del canal alfa


//RESULTADO
$mostrar_imagen_como_resultado = true;

if ($mostrar_imagen_como_resultado) {
    //Mostrar la imagen
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($destino);
} else {
    //Guardarla en otro archivo
    $rutaDestino = 'ruta-nueva.png';
    imagepng($destino, $rutaDestino);
}

//liberar recursos
imagedestroy($origen);
imagedestroy($destino);
```

**Resultado**

> Original:
>   [image]
>
> Rotada 90°:
>   [image]
>
> Rotada 76°:
>   [image]
>
> - Esta imagen la estoy generando desde este mismo script en un hosting gratuito.

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero ahora no funciona cuando son los grados por ejemplo 76, queda en negro .

Comment: @AlbertArias recién publiqué otro ejemplo, sólo cambiando los grados