# En android al tomar foto vertical, en el image view, la imagen sale girada 90 grados

Tags: android

Tengo problemas al subir una imagen a un servidor desde android.

Mi código para seleccionar imagen:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
    .setTitle("Seleccionar Imagen")
    .setPositiveButton("Galeria", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            tipoImagen = true;
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecciona Imagen"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_GALLERY);//PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_GALLERY=1
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Cámara", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            tipoImagen = false;
            Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(takePicture, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CAMERA);//PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CAMERA=5
        }
    })
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_dialer)
    .show();
```

Mi código para recoger la imagen:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        filePath = data.getData();
        uriPath = filePath;

        String realPath;
        // SDK < API11
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19)// SDK >= 11 && SDK < 19
        {
            realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(getActivity(), data.getData());
        }
        else// SDK > 19 (Android 4.4)
        {
            realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API19(getActivity(), data.getData());
        }
        globalPath = realPath;
        configImage(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT, data.getData().getPath(),realPath);
    }
    else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        filePath = data.getData();
        uriPath = filePath;

        String realPath;
        // SDK < API11
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19)// SDK >= 11 && SDK < 19
        {
            realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(getActivity(), data.getData());
        }
        else// SDK >= 19 (Android 4.4)
        {
            realPath = RealPathUtil.getRealPathFromURI_API19(getActivity(), data.getData());
        }
        globalPath = realPath;
        configImage(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT, data.getData().getPath(),realPath);
    }
}

private void configImage(int sdk, String uriPath, String realPath){
    Uri uriFromPath = Uri.fromFile(new File(realPath));

    try {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uriFromPath));
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    imagenFondo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    imagenFondo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    txtCamera.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    Log.d("HMKCODE", "Build.VERSION.SDK_INT:" + sdk);
    Log.d("HMKCODE", "URI Path:" + uriPath);
    Log.d("HMKCODE", "Real Path: " + realPath);
}
```

El problema es que si saco una imagen en **Vertical** cuando llega al servidor la imagen aparece rotada por defecto. Como puedo corregir esa rotación automatica.

**No solo rota la imagen al enviarla al servidor, si la muestro en un imageview tambien sale rotada**

Comment: No se resolverlo, pero esto me suena a que las imagenes que estas subiendo tienen en los metas de imagen la posición en la que esta siendo tomada, y donde muestras la imagen en el servidor no utilizas los metas para saber su orientacion. Mira a ver si encuentras algo de esto

Comment: muchas gracias, lo mirare @AngelCid si funciona, añade tu comentario como respuesta y lo valido

Comment: Funciona correctamente @AngelCid

Comment: yo tengo el mismo problema solo que yo tengo que poner la imagen en un imageview tomandola desde la camara, pero al tomarla con la camara frontal se pone acostada hacia la izquierda y al tomarla con la camara trasera se pone acostada hacia la derecha
al revisar las propiedades de las fotos se me pone que tiene de orientacion 90grados y 270 grados respectivamente,
lo que neccecito es ponerle orientacion 0grados para que se ponga bien derecha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado la solución gracias al comentario de [Angel Cid](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7246/angel-cid)

Lo que he echo es analizar la imagen una vez llega al servidor, en vez de modificarla desde android. El código PHP

```
<?php
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagenNoticia']['tmp_name'], $rutaFichero))
{
    $archivo = explode(".", $rutaFichero);

    if ($archivo[1] == 'jpg' || $archivo[1] == 'jpeg')
    {
        $imagenTemporal = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagenOriginal);
    }
    else if($archivo[1] == 'JPG' || $archivo[1] == 'JPEG')
    {
        $imagenTemporal = ImageCreateFromJPEG($imagenOriginal);
    }
    else if($archivo[1] == 'png')
    {
        $imagenTemporal = imagecreatefrompng($imagenOriginal);
    }
    else
    {
        $imagenTemporal = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagenOriginal);
    }

    $exifAux = exif_read_data($_FILES['imagenNoticia']['tmp_name']);
    if(isset($exifAux['Orientation']))
    {
        switch($exifAux['Orientation'])
        {
            case 8:
                $imagenTemporal = imagerotate($imagenTemporal, 90, 0);
                break;
            case 3:
                $imagenTemporal = imagerotate($imagenTemporal, 180, 0);
                break;
            case 6:
                $imagenTemporal = imagerotate($imagenTemporal, -90, 0);
                break;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hola. Tu solución es interesante; pero, como puede ser adaptada a la necesidad de girar imágenes que suben al servidor con orientación inesperada, y eventualmente podrían tener transparencias, valdría la pena que consideres integrar el planteamiento hecho por @Mariano en: [Rotar una imagen con fondo transparente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/73189/91033). Enriquecería mucho la respuesta por el nivel de generalidad logrado.

Answer (score 0):

Por desgracia, esto tiene un poco que ver con la fragmentación de `Android`. He tenido este mismo problema antes, y en un dispositivo `Samsung` salía girada, mientras que en otro diferente salía bien.

Lo que hice fue mirar la altura y anchura de la foto, y según eso decidir si estaba en vertical u horizontal.

Aunque también puedes usar [ExifInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html)

Con ella, puedes hacer algo como:

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(uri.getPath());
```

y obtener la orientación con:

```
int rotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
```

Comment: Ese código yalo habia usado, pero si la foto estaba en horizontal(correcta) me la giraba también. Pero gracias de todas formas @bob